# more pythonic/higher level/advanced operation challenge

Tags: python, sum, reduce

Purely for curiosity's sake:

## Assuming:

```
data = [
  {
    'quantity': Decimal(10),
    'price': Decimal(1.25)
  },
  ...
]

def func(data):
  quantity = Decimal()
  value = Decimal()

  for item in data:
    quantity += item['quantity']
    value += item['quantity'] * item['price']

  return quantity, value
```

## Question

The purpose of `func` is to return the **total** quantity and value in `data`

What other ways exist of achieving the same result?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about alternatives to working code. Probably more suitable for codereview.stackexchage.com.

Answer (score 1):

Same idea but using iteration

```
def fun(data):
    tons = sum(item['tons'] for item in data)
    value = sum(item['tons']*item['price'] for item in data)
    return tons, value
```

Comment: Good answer, I thought of this too. Requires two iterations.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
data = [{'quantity': 10.0,'price': 1.25},{'quantity': 8.0,'price': 2.0}]

(quantity, value) = [sum(x) for x in zip(*[(x['quantity'],x['price']*x['quantity']) for x in data])]

# quantity = 18 and value = 28.5
```

Comment: Please include an explanation as to why this code solves the asker's question.

Comment: This code does not correctly calculate either `quantity` nor `value`.  Run your code and you get quantity==22.5 which != 18 (10+8) and value == 24.5 which != 28.5 (10*1.25 + 8*2)

Comment: sorry, fixed...try now